# Print characters as a Matrix

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix

Below problem has a list of characters and number of columns as the input. Number of columns is not a constant and can vary with every input. 
Output should have all the rows fully occupied except for the last one.

```
list: a b c d e f g
colums: 3

Wrong:
a b c
d e f
g

Wrong:
a d g
b e
c f

Correct:
a d f
b e g
c
```

I have tried below:

```
public static void printPatern(List<Character> list, int cols) {

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {

        for (int j = i; j < list.size(); j += cols) {
            System.out.print(list.get(j));

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It gives output as (which is wrong):

```
a d g
b e
c f
```

I am trying to come with an algorithm to print the correct output. I want to know what are the different ways to solve this problem. Time and Space complexity doesn't matter. Also above method which I tried is wrong because it takes columns as the parameter but that's actually acting as the number of rows.

FYI: This is not a HOMEWORK problem.

Comment: your require output not makes any sense?

Comment: is row number constant to 3?

Comment: Nope. That's number of columns and it can vary.

Comment: ok this something tricky algorithm. will get back to you with answer

Comment: @Dhiraj It seems that really dont understand the problem. The number of rows needs to be computed, based on the length of the list and the number of columns required.

Comment: @GhostCat Number of columns doesn't have to be computed. It is an input to the method.

Comment: I understood it. i will give you answer soon. workin on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally able to design the algorithm for this problem
Please refer below java code same

```
 public class puzzle{
        public static void main(String[] args){

            String list[] = { "a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j" };
            int column = 3;

            int rows = list.length/column; //Calculate total full rows
            int lastRowElement = list.length%column;//identify number of elements in last row
            if(lastRowElement >0){
                rows++;//add inclomplete row to total number of full filled rows
            }
            //Iterate over rows
             for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                int j=i;
                int columnIndex = 1;
                while(j < list.length && columnIndex <=column ){
                    System.out.print("\t"+list[j]);
                    if(columnIndex<=lastRowElement){
                        if(i==rows-1 && columnIndex==lastRowElement){
                            j=list.length; //for last row display nothing after column index reaches to number of elements in last row
                        }else{
                            j += rows; //for other rows if columnIndex is less than or equal to number of elements in last row then add j value by number of rows
                        }

                    }else {
                       if(lastRowElement==0){
                          j += rows;
                       }else{
                        j += rows-1; //for column greater than number of element in last row add j = row-1 as last row will not having the column for this column index.
                       }
                    }

                    columnIndex++;//Increase column Index by 1;
                }

                System.out.println();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works for odd number of elements but not for even number. Like list = a,b,c,d,e,f and columns = 2.

Comment: Thanks Dhiraj. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably homework; so I am not going to do it for you, but give you some hints to get going. There are two points here:

- computing the correct number of rows
- computing the "pattern" that you need when looping your list so that you print the expected result

For the first part, you can look into the modulo operation; and for the second part: start iterating your list "on paper" and observe how you are printing the correct result manually.

Obviously, that second part is the more complicated one. It might help if you realize that printing "column by column" is straight forward. So when we take your correct example and print the **indexes** instead of values, you get:

```
0 3 6
1 4 7
2 5
```

Do that repeatedly for different input; and you will soon discover the pattern of indexes that you need to print "row by row".

Comment: I tried this way too. The problem here is, the pattern for an odd number of elements is:
    
    0 3 5,
    1 4 6,
    2
    
whereas for an even number of elements it's like:

    0 2 4,
    1 3 5

The difference is not constant when the number of elements are odd.

Comment: Sure. Because it is not as simple as just adding a constant value. The factor that comes into play here is the number of elements that you have to print within the last row. In other words: the function that selects the list indexes to print for any row depends on that value, too (not only on the number of columns!)